# She stole her best friend’s boyfriend (from her)

Tags: prepositional-phrases, personal-pronouns, redundancy

> [*She stole **her best friend**’s boyfriend **(from her)***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english-spanish/steal)

What is the reason for adding the redundant phrase **from her** after mentioning that it's **her best friend**?

Comment: I guess you could ask the same question about the Spanish version where _(le)_ is added in brackets? It's probably a nice way to show how you would translate that construction - it's a translation example, not an actual sentence from a paper.

Comment: For reasons, you'll need to ask whoever wrote the original.

Comment: @oerkelens _My ex stole all **my** money from **me**_ https://www.reddit.com/r/relationships/comments/6irobp/my_ex_25m_stole_all_my_money_from_me_24f_after_i/

Comment: @Lawrence ?? https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=for%20reasons

Comment: Yup, semantically it is redundant. But we're talking _language_. Is your actual question why people include redundant information in their language? I'm sure there is a bunch of interesting answers to that, but I think that question would be better suited to linguistics.stackechange

Comment: @GJC No, I'm using "for reasons" in the plain vanilla sense of "to find out why".

Comment: Note that not every combination of words you happen to find in some obscure slang-dictionary is always used as slang... In this case _for reasons, do x_ is a very simply sentence like _for water, open tap_.

Comment: In passing, this phrasing is used in Tennessee Waltz.
  I was dancin' with my darlin' to the Tennessee Waltz
When an old friend I happened to see
I introduced her to my loved one
And while they were dancin'

My friend stole my sweetheart from me
I remember the night and the Tennessee Waltz
Now I know just how much I have lost
Yes, I lost my little darlin' the night they were playing
The beautiful Tennessee Waltz

Comment: I suppose picture nouns need further specifics. _They stole Constable's 'The Combine Harvester' from the Sarjent Gallery_, but one's boyfriend can surely only be stolen from ... one. As Richard says, nowadays 'one' may be male or female, but adding 'from him' etc seems a contrived way to specify.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious possibilities are that (a) her best friend is a "her", in which case the parenthetical is redundant and one could delete it, and (b) her best friend is not a "her", but a "him" (or something else not a "her"), in which case the parenthetical is not redundant but essential. If we assume the author knows how to write, he or she has added the parenthetical to make it crystal clear to the reader that her best friend is a "her", and not a "him" or something else.

Comment: Or as opposed to *she stole her best friend's boyfriend **from his chores at work**.* In that context, *from her* is in no way redundant at all. It's only redundant if you assume a certain interpretation barring further context. And even if it *is* redundant, redundancies often have a stylistic basis—to emphasize something.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase is taken from a Spanish bilingual dictionary, the parenthesis is probably used to clarify to Spanish speakers who the "best friend" refers to, in this case a woman.

In English "friend" is gender neutral, but in many Romance languages it is gendered, e.g. in Italian it's *amica* (f), *amico* (m), and in Spanish it's *amiga*, and *amigo*.